# How to arrange divs to be more mobile friendly without using bootstrap?

Tags: css, media, responsive

I'm trying to learn css and flex-box/grid. I want to re-arrange the divs so the position of the divs change when resizing the screen. I've tried position absolute, relative and flex, but can't get it to work as intended. The idea is get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYVhN.jpg).

Here is a codepen of the code I've so far:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYOaEJ)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Data</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="outer-col-1">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="outer-col-2">
   <header><h1>TITLE</h1></header>
    <div class="inner-row">
      <div class="inner-col">
     <article>
   <h2>ARTICLE TITLE</h2>
    <picture>
   
   <source srcset="images/binare-270.png" media="(max-width: 440px)">
   <source srcset="images/binare-400.png">
   <img src="images/binare-400.png" alt="image desc">
  </picture> 
   <p>LOREM IMPSUM</p>
      <p>LOREM IMPSUM</p>
      <p>LOREM IMPSUM</p>
        
      </article>
        
    <footer>FOOTERFOOTERFOOTER</footer>
      </div>
     <aside>
      <p>LOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM IMPSUMLOREM </p>
</aside>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have added the flexbox layout without using bootstrap as per sample image. And also you can adjust the body `max-width` based on your requirement. I hope this will suitable for you.

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*,
:after,
:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: .5rem;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

a {
    color: white;
}

nav,
aside {
    flex: 0 0 10rem;
}

header,
nav,
aside,
main,
footer {
    color: white;
    background: #2b97f3;
    padding: .5rem;
}

header,
nav,
footer,
aside,
main {
    margin: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}

nav {
    order: 1;
}

.wrapper-inner {
    order: 2;
}

footer {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.main-inner {
    display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    nav {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .main-inner {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
    }
    .main-inner .content {
        order: 2;
    }
    .main-inner .aside {
        order: 1;
    }
    .wrapper {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <nav>
  <h3>Navigation</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div class="wrapper-inner">
  <header>
   <h3>Header</h3>
  </header>
  <div class="main-inner">   
    <div class="content">
     <main>
      <h3>Content Area</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error quod cumque at, qui excepturi illo vel, deserunt alias incidunt distinctio adipisci. Quisquam ducimus fuga ipsam modi accusamus, eaque unde porro.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo vitae hic provident incidunt, illum voluptatibus voluptates voluptate esse ea, vero, beatae necessitatibus maxime minus ex doloribus dolorem eum quisquam optio.</p>

      <h4>More Content</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte reprehenderit, quod necessitatibus hic vel dicta pariatur illum! Omnis!</p>
     </main>
     <footer>
      <h3>Footer</h3>
     </footer>
    </div> 
   <aside>
    <h3>Sidebar</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam necessitatibus velit voluptatem architecto eum magni quasi totam adipisci, suscipit, iure laboriosam deleniti modi sit excepturi accusamus minus debitis rem. Delectus.</p>
   </aside>
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: The code works great and helped me understand a bit better the issue, but the sidebar won't go below the header when resizing other than that, everything else works, thanks.

Comment: If everything ok check the tick icon becz this will be helpful for other persons.